# Is there a cleaner way to add a new property with unique values to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm just learning js now (late to the party I know) and I have the following code and I was wondering if it could be written in a cleaner/simpler way?

Also, ideally, instead of using "if (obj.id === 1)" I would like to iterate through the array and add age based on the sequence i.e. [0] would become '32' and so on.

```
const students = [ // Three objects, each with four properties
 {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Mark',
  profession: 'Developer',
  skill: 'JavaScript'
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Ariel',
  profession: 'Developer',
  skill: 'HTML'
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Jason',
  profession: 'Designer',
  skill: 'CSS'
 },
];

const studentsWithAge = students.map(obj => {
if (obj.id === 1) {
 return {...obj, age: '32'};
 } else if (obj.id === 2) {
  return {...obj, age: '26'};
 } else if (obj.id === 3) {
  return {...obj, age: '28'};
 }
 return obj;
});

console.log(studentsWithAge);

// output
// [
//  {
//   id: 1,
//   name: 'Mark',
//   profession: 'Developer',
//   skill: 'JavaScript',
//   age: '32'
//  },
//  {
//   id: 2,
//   name: 'Ariel',
//   profession: 'Developer',
//   skill: 'HTML',
//   age: '26'
//  },
//  {
//   id: 3,
//   name: 'Jason',
//   profession: 'Designer',
//   skill: 'CSS',
//   age: '28'
//  }
// ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map the array into the object like so:

```js
const ages = ['32', '26', '28'];
const studentsWithAge = students.map(obj => { ...obj, age: ages[obj.id-1] });
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an `ages` array and use the index to map the value to the corresponding object.

```js
const students = [ // Three objects, each with four properties
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Mark',
    profession: 'Developer',
    skill: 'JavaScript'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ariel',
    profession: 'Developer',
    skill: 'HTML'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Jason',
    profession: 'Designer',
    skill: 'CSS'
  },
];

const ages = [32, 26, 28];

const result = students.map((s, i) => {
  return { ...s, age: ages[i] }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is true, another way to add ages by the id is the following code. Just use `id`s as object key and age as value.

The following code check if `id` exists in the `ages` const then add it to the `studentsWithAge`. It works exactly like your code.

```
const ages = {1: '32', 2: '26', 3: '28'};

const studentsWithAge = students.map(obj => { 
    if(ages[obj.id]) obj.age = ages[obj.id]; 
    return obj;
});
```

But if you're sure all ids have age value simpler code like this could be used:

```
const ages = {1: '32', 2: '26', 3: '28'};
const studentsWithAge = students.map(obj => ({...obj, age: ages[obj.id]}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on how you store the `ages` data. Here's an example if you keep the `ages` data in an array of objects, just like you keep the `students` data.

This approach is easily extended, you can add any other fields related to the student to the object.

```js
students = [
  {id: 1,name: 'Mark',profession: 'Developer',skill: 'JavaScript'},
  {id: 2,name: 'Ariel',profession: 'Developer',skill: 'HTML'},
  {id: 3,name: 'Jason',profession: 'Designer',skill: 'CSS'}];
 
extraInfo = [{id: 1, age:32}, {id:2, age: 26}, {id:3, age: 33}];

const result = students.map((s)=>
  ({ ...s, ...extraInfo.find((a) => a.id === s.id) })
);
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Much appreciated.